# CSS mouse hover moves another div down

Tags: html, css

WEB URL: http://riiul.xyz/kalista.html

Im trying to make a lil blog page, I have **problem** with hovers, if you move your mouse over the icon on webpage it pop ups a textbox, but the textbox moves down another div "Soovitatavad ruunid"

Im really beginner at these things but I myself think it might be something with margins. I can make it work with position: absolute, but if there comes more divs and the content gets longer, then the scrolling takes these position: absolute thingies with it.

Here is my code:

```css
.bgimg {
  background-image: url("../img/kalista.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: auto;
  z-index: -999;
}
.box {
  background-image: url('../img/kalistatop.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: auto;
  border: solid 3px #CCCCCC;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgba(0, 56, 78, 0.7);
  padding: 4px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -998;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
.pealkiri {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  z-index: -997;
  text-align: center;
}
.summonerid-pealkiri {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: -996;
}
.summonerid {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -995;
}
.summoner-wrap {
  width: 64px;
}
.summoner-wrap .summoner-content {
  display: none;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #0d0d0d;
  width: 275px;
  z-index: -994;
}
.summoner-wrap:hover .summoner-content {
  display: block;
}
.runed-pealkiri {
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: -993;
}
.runed {
  z-index: -992;
```

```html
<?php $url='http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/1/18/Kalista_OriginalSkin.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141105014341' ; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Myrka</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="pixelhint.com">
  <meta name="description" content="Myrka Weeb" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- Styles -->
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/logo.png" title="Myrka" alt="Myrka" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- end logo -->
    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Kodu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="minust.html">Minust</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="tiim.html">Tiim</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="paevik.html">Päevik</a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation menu -->

    <div class="footer clearfix">
      <ul class="social clearfix">
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/kvcmyrka" class="fb" data-title="Facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <!--<li><a href="#" class="google" data-title="Google +"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="behance" data-title="Behance"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="twitter" data-title="Twitter"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dribble" data-title="Dribble"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rss" data-title="RSS"></a></li>-->
      </ul>
      <!-- end social -->

      <div class="rights">
        <p>Copyright © 2016 Myrka Weeb.</p>
        <p>myrka@riiul.xyz</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end rights -->
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
  </header>
  <!-- end header -->

  <!-- Õpetus -->
  <section class="main clearfix">
    <div class="bgimg" style="font-family: raleway-regular, arial">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="pealkiri">
          <h1 style="color:#ffffff;">Kalista - Hüplev kits</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="summonerid-pealkiri">
          <h2 style="color: #ffffff;">Soovitatavad summonerid</h2>
          <div class="summonerid">
            <div class="summoner-wrap" style="float:left; padding-right:5px;">
              <img src="/img/heal.png" alt="Hiil" width="64" height="64" style="border:2px solid black" />
              <div class="summoner-content">
                <h3 style="color: #fff;">Hiil</p>
        <p style="color: #fff; font-size:12px;">Level: <span style="color: #1aff1a">1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Raadius: <span style="color: #1aff1a">850</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cooldown: <span style="color: #1aff1a">240</span></p>
        <p style="color: #fff; font-size:12px;">Heals the caster and the allied champion nearest to the caster's cursor (or the most wounded ally if no target is near the cursor) by 90-345 health, and gives affected champions +30% movement speed for 1 seconds. Heal is 50% less effective on allies previously healed with another Summoner Spell Heal within the past 35 seconds. 240 second cooldown.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="summoner-wrap" style="float:right; padding-left:5px;">
       <img src="/img/flash.png" alt="Fläsh" width="64" height="64" style="border:2px solid black" />
        <div class="summoner-content">
        <h3 style="color: #fff;">Fläsh</p>
        <p style="color: #fff; font-size:12px;">Level: <span style="color: #1aff1a">8</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Raadius: <span style="color: #1aff1a">425</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cooldown: <span style="color: #1aff1a">300</span></p>
        <p style="color: #fff; font-size:12px;">Teleports your champion toward your cursor's location. 300 second cooldown.</p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="runed-pealkiri">
    <h2 style="color: #ffffff;">Soovitatavad ruunid</h2>
     <div class="runed">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>  
 <!-- end main -->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And you have your HTML messed up. Check the nesting... You have `</p>` instead of `</h3>`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include only the code relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple fix would be using:

```
.summoner-wrap .summoner-content {
    visibility: hidden;                     /* Change here */
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    background-color: #262626;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #0d0d0d;
    width: 275px;
    z-index: -994;
}

.summoner-wrap:hover .summoner-content {
    visibility: visible;                    /* Change here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast awnser :)
It seemed to fix moveing problem, but now second div header is way down,
I would like to have it there, so the hover box just covers it, when opened:
http://www.upload.ee/image/5760164/123.png

Comment: @SanderRistimägi Ha ha.. I guessed. Give `margin-left: -69px` or something: `.summoner-content`

Comment: @SanderRistimägi On the second alone: `<div class="summoner-content" style="margin-left: -69px;">`

Comment: Uhm :D I think you understood me wrong, i need this div to be right under the images, no space between :D (http://www.upload.ee/image/5760164/123.png - like this)
 <div class="runed-pealkiri">
    <h2 style="color: #ffffff;">Soovitatavad ruunid</h2>
     <div class="runed">
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: @SanderRistimägi Then very simple. Add `position: absolute` to the `.summoner-wrap .summoner-content` at the end. `:D`

Comment: I have tried it, it worked, but later when i added more content to the page, and scrolling was needed then all the "position absolute" divs came down with the scrolling like background :S (moved with scrolling, my english isn't that good, hope you understand :D )

Comment: Er... The problem is with the way you layout the HTML. That needs a lot of changes.

Comment: Oooh ok, i rly should have started making page from simple shit xD

Comment: @SanderRistimägi Don't worry... There must be small changes you need to make... That's all. You know editing existing code is a pain.